# Executing a function while listening to a changing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using iosSlider to display artwork here : http://artiris.clients.twi.tl/galeries/galerie-bleue

I wish to add a blur filter to works that are outside the center. Although the plugin does not have an 'active' class setting, I could easily add one with a simple function to do this.

Here's the tricky part. I want the blur to transition in and out. Not with a time value, but rather I wish for the transition to be linked to the slider movement. For example, as an artwork approaches the center, the blur value will be connected to the movement and will be 0 when the artwork is in the center. I want this because the slider supports touch.

The slider object does provide it's real time position so I can figure out what blur value to set. However, write a do/while loop for this, the browser just crashes. Also there are onSlideStart and onSlideComplete events but I can't get my head around how to execute a function on one event and stop it on an other.

All in all, I just need someone to steer me in the right direction as to how I can do this cleanly and effectively.

Thanks

Comment: I've tried a do/while loop which starts on onSlideStart and listens to the changing value of the slider while it is not equal to the value of the next slide being in the center, but that just crashes the browser.

Comment: Yeah, remember that browsers are not multi-threaded: if you have a while loop in your javascript, you can't have an event "turn it off" - the event code will never be run, because the loop will never be switched out.

Comment: I was also thinking that it might be possible to achieve this using only CSS transitions since all the movement is CSS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here it is. http://artiris.clients.twi.tl/galeries/galerie-bleue

Not sure if it's the best way of doing it but it seems to work!

When the slider starts moving, I start a timeout which runs a function every 100ms. The timeout clears when the slider stops moving.

Here is my function :

```
function adjustFilter() {
    var nodes = $gallerySlider.data('iosslider').slideNodes,
        stage = $gallerySlider.data('iosslider').stageWidth,
        matrix =    $slider.css("-webkit-transform") ||
                    $slider.css("-moz-transform") ||
                    $slider.css("-ms-transform") ||
                    $slider.css("-o-transform") ||
                    $slider.css("transform"),
        matrixArray = matrixToArray(matrix),
        position =  Math.abs(matrixArray[4]);

    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var $node = $(nodes[i]),
            nodeMatrix =    $node.css("-webkit-transform") ||
                            $node.css("-moz-transform") ||
                            $node.css("-ms-transform") ||
                            $node.css("-o-transform") ||
                            $node.css("transform"),
            nodeMatrixArray = matrixToArray(nodeMatrix),
            nodePosition = Math.abs(nodeMatrixArray[4]),
            distance = Math.abs(Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(nodePosition-position), stage*(-1)), stage)),
            tx = distance/stage;

        $node.css({ '-webkit-filter' : 'blur('+tx*10/2+'px) grayscale('+tx+')' })
    }
}
```

Basically it gets the position of the slider. Then for each node I get it's current position and calculates the distance from the center. This distance is than normalised so that it's never greater than the width of a slide. I then use that number to set the blur and grayscale for every node in real time. This way the effect is continuous.

So far, performance seems to be good. In any case, I'm going to run the function only when the filter property is supported by the browser.

If anyone can suggest on ways I can improve this code, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some kind of "onDrag" event going off constantly, there are only two ways I can think of handling this.

**First**: a `setTimeout` that goes every millisecond or so, which adjusts the blur. This is almost certainly **not** a good option, but it is technically *an* option. This could cause performance issues, particularly on low-speed devices. It would also mean that the blur could be inconstant, as the timeout would probably not actually get run every millisecond.

You can't use a loop for it and enable/disable the loop according to events, as you suggested in the comments, because javascript is single-threaded: once the loop started, no other javascript will ever be run, and you'll always lock up your browser.

**Second**: A CSS only solution. If the movement is CSS only, then with any luck the blur can be done in the same way. Sadly I'm not a CSS expert, so I'm not sure of the best way of doing this.

Sorry, this isn't a very good answer to your question, but I wanted to explain the javascript option for you, and the reason for why you probably shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

iosSlider dev reporting in with some insight.

You could add your own function inside the touchmove event within the iosSlider plugin. This function would then fire alongside the iosSlider dragging. I recommend placing it somewhere after line 1806. If I was to code it, that's how I would do it.